# kubectl access to Google Cloud Container Engine fails

Tags: kubernetes, gcloud, google-kubernetes-engine, kubectl

In Google Cloud Platform I have a Container-Cluster with three running instances. I now want to connect from my terminal to be able to run `kubectl` commands. For this I ran the command

```
gcloud container clusters get-credentials cluster-1 --zone europe-west1-b --project project-id
```

I am using the real project name of course. This is the command shown by the dashboard when clicking on 'connect with the cluster'. The output of this command is:

```
Fetching cluster endpoint and auth data.
kubeconfig entry generated for cluster-1.
```

But when I run `kubectl`commands afterwards like `kubectl cluster-info` I always get:

```
Unable to connect to the server: oauth2: cannot fetch token: 400 Bad Request
Response: {
  "error" : "invalid_grant",
  "error_description" : "Token has been revoked."
}
```

What am I missing here? `gcloud` commands like `gcloud container clusters list` work

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I tried from a different machine at home, and there it was working after installing and setting up gcloud. I think that on my work machine there is still an oauth token stored with which I authenticated to a different google account I used for a test.

**Edit:** I got it running now. the problem was that I missed the second of the necessary calls:

```
gcloud auth login
gcloud auth application-default login
```